# SQL rank starting with 2

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
select 
    TRANSACTION_DT,
    SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
    KEY_ID,
    EMAIL,
    PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID, 
    rank () over (partition by SUBSCRIPTION_ID,KEY_ID order by TRANSACTION_DT desc) as rnk 
from "DC"."BW_BOOKINGS"
where email='abc@gmail.com'
```

The above SQL statement result table looks like this

| TRANSACTION_DT | SUBSCRIPTION_ID | KEY_ID | EMAIL | PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID | RNK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-14 09:42:47.710 -0700 | S107283 | 122693 | abc@gmail.com | 143510 | 1 |
| 2021-07-14 09:42:47.710 -0700 | S107283 | 122693 | abc@gmail.com | 139724 | 1 |
| 2020-07-14 09:22:14.033 -0700 | S107283 | 122693 | abc@gmail.com | 143510 | 3 |
| 2020-07-14 09:22:14.033 -0700 | S107283 | 122693 | abc@gmail.com | 139724 | 3 |

But when I change the SQL statement to this

```
select * from (
    select 
        TRANSACTION_DT,
        SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
        KEY_ID, 
        EMAIL,
        PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID, 
        rank () over (partition by SUBSCRIPTION_ID,KEY_ID order by TRANSACTION_DT desc) as rnk 
    from "DC"."BW_BOOKINGS"
) t
where email='abc@gmail.com'
```

My table looks like this:

| TRANSACTION_DT | SUBSCRIPTION_ID | KEY_ID | EMAIL | PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID | RNK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-14 09:42:47.710 -0700 | S107283 | 122693 | abc@gmail.com | 143510 | 3 |
| 2021-07-14 09:42:47.710 -0700 | S107283 | 122693 | abc@gmail.com | 139724 | 3 |
| 2020-07-14 09:22:14.033 -0700 | S107283 | 122693 | abc@gmail.com | 139724 | 5 |
| 2020-07-14 09:22:14.033 -0700 | S107283 | 122693 | abc@gmail.com | 143510 | 5 |

I want to get results from the table only when rnk=1, but the rank in table 2 starts with 3 which is not helping me to filter out results on where rnk=1. Also, Can anyone tell me why the order of PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID chases in row 3.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> Snowflake - please correct your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second solution is ranking ALL rows, and then you throw away rows not match the email address, thus you have already "lost 1"

The filter need to happen before the ranking function, not after it.

So if you want only RANK = 1 then you can qualify:

```
select 
    TRANSACTION_DT,
    SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
    KEY_ID, 
    EMAIL,
    PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID, 
    rank () over (partition by SUBSCRIPTION_ID,KEY_ID order by TRANSACTION_DT desc) as rnk 
from "DC"."BW_BOOKINGS"
qualify rnk  = 1
```

if you want only the RANK 1 rows for email X then do the filtering in the WHERE, then [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) to keep the wanted rows:

```
select 
    TRANSACTION_DT,
    SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
    KEY_ID, 
    EMAIL,
    PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID, 
    rank () over (partition by SUBSCRIPTION_ID,KEY_ID order by TRANSACTION_DT desc) as rnk 
from "DC"."BW_BOOKINGS"
where email='abc@gmail.com'
qualify rnk  = 1
```

Greg's note, "if you don't want the rank you don't need it" looks like:

```
select 
    TRANSACTION_DT,
    SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
    KEY_ID, 
    EMAIL,
    PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID
from "DC"."BW_BOOKINGS"
where email='abc@gmail.com'
qualify rank () over (partition by SUBSCRIPTION_ID,KEY_ID order by TRANSACTION_DT desc) = 1
```

Comment: @user18457660, if the purpose of the window function is to filter to a specific row and the rank does not matter otherwise, you can use the second approach Simeon shows but move the window function out of the select and into the qualify and compare to 1 as shown. This will avoid projecting the rank column if it's not needed in the result set.